# pick two elements in rdd in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I have a rdd

```
rdd1=sc.parallelize(['a','b','c','d'])
```

I want to generate a rdd which pick two elements from rdd1

```
[('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','c'),('b','d'),('c','d')]
```

I tried

```
rdd1.cartesian(rdd1)
```

but

```
('a','a'),('b','b'),('c','c'),('d','d')
```

also in it.

Comment: `.filter(lambda t: t[0] != t[1])`?

Comment: Add in a filter step `rdd1.cartesian(rdd1).filter(lambda x: (x[0] != x[1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the solution below. I am not very much sure about performance with RDD approach. It would be very easy and efficient using dataframe approach.

```
from pyspark import  SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

rdd1=sc.parallelize(['a','b','c','d']).zipWithUniqueId()
rdd2=rdd1.map(lambda l : (l[1],l[0]))
rdd3=rdd2.cartesian(rdd2).filter(lambda t: t[0][0] < t[1][0]).map(lambda l : (l[0][1],l[1][1]))

Result:
rdd3.collect()
Out[29]: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Hope, this will help.

Thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools`

```
import itertools
rdd1=sc.parallelize(['a','b','c','d'])

>>> list(itertools.combinations(rdd1.collect(),2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: Good one, just one doubt, do we need rdd for using itertools. Even second step can be removed in this case.

Comment: No you don't need an `rdd`.  I used one because the context was `rdd`